# How to Find the Square Root of -1 in mod 1130

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms

I am currently taking an introductory abstract algebra course and I am at a loss as to how to start approaching this problem (I find myself struggling in this field so far). I am currently being asked in this exercise to find the square root of -1 in mod 1130 given the fact that we know that:
    $$ 1130 = (17^2) + (29^2)$$

Can anyone please walk me through the steps for the solution? I apologize for the formatting of the numbers as I do not know how to have them displayed in mathematical symbols and numbers on this site.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about inverses modulo $m$? We get "lucky," since $(29)(39)=1131$.

Comment: I do not, could you possibly expand a little on it for me?

Answer (score 1):

We have $17^2\equiv -(29)^2\pmod{1130}$.  Let $c$ be the inverse of $29$ modulo $1130$. It so happens that $c$ can be taken to be $39$.  Then multiplying through by $c^2$ we get $(39\cdot 17)^2\equiv -1\pmod{1130}$.

**Remark:** When $a$ is relatively prime to $m$, finding the inverse of $a$ modulo $m$ can be done quite efficiently using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

If we are given a representation of $m$ as a sum $x^2+y^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime to $m$, we can use the procedure of the main post to solve the congruence $w^2\equiv -1\pmod{m}$.